# Como passar os dados em PHP

Tags: php, html

Estou com uma duvida, estou fazendo um sistema de registro de pedidos, porém ao clicar no botão eu quero que esses dados apareçam em outra pagina(eu havia feito em javascript porém isso compromete a segurança, queria saber como fazer em php): exemplo:

aqui o registro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa segunda imagem, ao clicar em finalizar, acima, quero que o registro desses pedidos apareça aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="container">


<div class="last-liner">
                <p>Valor do Pedido: <span id="resultado" class="resultado"></span></p>
                <p>Taxa de Entrega: <span id="txa" class="txa">5.00</span></p>
                <p>Total: <span id="tot" class="tot"></span></p>
                <button id="finalizar" class="btn btn-round" name="finalizar" type="button">Finalizar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Isso não é necessariamente `PHP`. Você precisa aprender o básico sobre o atributo método (method attribute) do `FORM` em `HTML`. O `PHP` captura esses dados enviados pelo `FORM` num `array` e depois fica fácil pra usar ou mostrar. Também é possível fazer `POST` com `JavaScript`, mas isso já me parece avançado demais para vc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harakin, você não postou os códigos mas conheço eles de outra pergunta.
Edite sua pergunta colocando os códigos para melhor entendimento dos outros usuários tanto da pergunta quanto da resposta.

Aqui está a solução para o seu caso.

No script adicione estas duas linhas
`document.getElementById("vpedido").value = parseFloat(valorTotal).toFixed(2);
 document.getElementById("total").value = parseFloat(valorTotal+5).toFixed(2);`

HTML - incluídos   `<input type="hidden" id="vpedido" name="vpedido" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" value="" />`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".pizza-add-sub").append('<div class="plus qty-pizza">+</div><div class="mines qty-pizza">-</div>');
  $(".qty-pizza").on("click", function() {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
    if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
      // Don't allow decrementing below zero
      if (oldValue > 0) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
      } else {
        newVal = 0;
      }
    }
    $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);

    var valorTotal = 0;
    var valoresMultiplicar = 0;
    $(".qtdpedidos").each(function() {
      valorTotal += parseFloat($(this).data("preco") * $(this).val());
    })

    $(".item span").each(function() {
      valoresMultiplicar += parseFloat($(this).html());
    })

        if (valorTotal==0){
            $("#tot").text("");
            $("#resultado").text('');
        }else{
            $("#tot").text('R$'+(parseFloat(valorTotal+5).toFixed(2)));
            $("#resultado").text('R$'+parseFloat(valorTotal).toFixed(2));
            document.getElementById("vpedido").value = parseFloat(valorTotal).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("total").value = parseFloat(valorTotal+5).toFixed(2);

        }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="PaginaDestino.php">  
<div class="media-body">
<div class="quantity">
  <div class="pizza-add-sub">
    <input data-preco="10.00" type="text" id="qtdpedidos" class="qtdpedidos" value="0" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item" class="pizza-price">
   <span id="Span1" class="pizza">P. Unit R$10.00</span>
</div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="vpedido" name="vpedido" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submeter" name="B1">
</form>

    <div class="last-liner">
      <p>Valor do Pedido: <span id="resultado" class="resultado"></span></p>
      <p>Taxa de Entrega: <span id="txa" class="txa">5.00</span></p>
      <p>Total: <span id="tot" class="tot"></span></p>
    </div>
```

**Pagina que recebe os dados**

```
<?php
$vpedido = $_POST['vpedido'];
$total = $_POST['total'];
?>


<div class="last-liner">
     <p>Valor do Pedido: <span id="resultado" class="resultado"><?php echo $vpedido;?></span></p>
     <p>Taxa de Entrega: <span id="txa" class="txa">5.00</span></p>
     <p>Total: <span id="tot" class="tot"><?php echo $total;?></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer com que os dados sejam exibidos dentro de tags `input`, que podem ser colocadas com o parâmetro `readonly` que faz com que os valores não sejam modificados e o `value` com os valores que aparecem na primeira tela que são as suas variáveis.

Vou colocar um código simples para que você entenda como fazer.

O input está estilizado para não parecer um input.

```css
.last-liner input{
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="last-liner">
  <form action="pagina.php" method="post">
   <p>Valor: <input type="text" name="valor" value="5.99" readonly="readonly"></p>
   <input type="submit" value="Finalizar">
  </form>
</div>
```

A parte em PHP pode ser assim:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['valor'])) {
  $valor = $_POST['valor'];
  echo '<p> Valor: '.$valor.'</p>';
}
?>
```